# Play boot sound right after splash screen

Tags: python, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I saw many guides online to run a script at startup but all I found so far runs after logged in to the pi. In my case, I would like to run a script right after the splash screen. I saw some guides online on how to customise the splash screen but it's not exactly what I need. I'm not sure how to adapt my code and I'm afraid that if there's error in the code, my pi won't boot. Here's the script that I want to run. It plays sound through an active buzzer:

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
# Set trigger PIN according with your cabling
signalPIN = 26

# Set PIN to output
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(signalPIN,GPIO.OUT)
class soundGen:
    
    def soundFunc(self,function):
        default = "Not found"
        return getattr(self, 'case_' + str(function), lambda: default)()
    
    def case_1(self):#Startup boot      
        return [1,0,1,0],[0.2,0.1,0.5,0]
        
    def soundPLayer(self, select):
        pin, gap = self.soundFunc(select)
        i=0
        for n in pin:
            GPIO.output(signalPIN,pin[i])
            time.sleep(gap[i])
            i=i+1
ss = soundGen()
function = 4
# cleanup will free PINS and exit will terminate code execution
ss.soundPLayer(function)

GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: `I would like to run a script at the rainbow splash screen` - impossible - I don't think the CPU is even initialised yet at that stage, let alone enough of the operating system to run python

Comment: @JaromandaX This one here shows how to customise the splash screen: [link](http://www.mrhobbytronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Raspberry-Pi-Splash-Screen.txt). I figured it would be possible to just adapt the code above?

Comment: you said "rainbow splash screen" - I assumed you meant the "rainbow" that appears when you first turn on the pi, not some splash screen that is **added** some time later by playing a video using omxplayer - just add audio to the video you play

Comment: @JaromandaX I was under the impression that they replaced that rainbow splash screen. So I thought i would be possible to play sound instead at that point in time. I'll modify my question.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, the earliest moment for the boot sound is right after the SystemD sound target:

```
[Unit]
Description=Boot Sound
Requires=sound.target
After=sound.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/aplay /boot/sound.wav

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```